# Recommended way of storing and accessing key value pairs and multiple integer values with the help of memory mapped IO

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

In a java program, I have a requirement of temporarily storing many  records- one record consists of a key, a object  as well as an integer value. The total processing will be for millions of records, but I plan to delete one record after processing has been completed on it... After that another record is inserted, processing is done on it, then it is deleted.... and so on...

What is the best way of storing such values with the help of memory mapped IO?

I can see samples for mapping byte buffers, but how do I store multiple records, and then retrieve them... Do I have to store the position numbers as I add records to the file storage, and use these to retrieve the data? Then I will have to create another array to store position numbers... Is there any recommended way of storing/retrieving data using memory mapped IO in java?

Comment: The easiest way is to install a copy of MySQL and use that.  It includes a lovely caching mechanism which probably counts as memory-mapped I/O.  You'll have to serialize the java object of course, but that's a problem that's been solved.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - the records need to be temporarily stored in memory- some processing will be done on each record and then each record is discarded-- i tried using traditional arraylists and hashmaps, but even if i remove an element from a hashmap (or arraylist) after I have done processing on that element, it still remains in memory- that is why i am looking at memory mapped io...

Comment: @Arvind: Why would it stay in memory if you've removed it from the map? If it stays in memory, it means that either you still have a reference to the record, or that GC doesn't need to run because the JVM has enough memory available. And why do you need to store many records if you insert one, process it, and then remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use WeakHashmap
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), if you can create combined key based on `records key/int pair` and value as `object` then you can store it in `HashMap` and delete values from hashMap in constant time operation.

---

Example:

```
    //Constructs a new empty HashMap with default initial capacity        
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

    //Key would be combination of "record key/int pair"
    hashMap.put(Key1, new Integer(1)); 
    hashMap.put(Key2, new Integer(2));
    hashMap.put(Key3, new Integer(3));

    //You can remove values from HashMap in constant time using remove
    hashMap.remove(Key1);
```